# Unable to load library (libFile.so) on jboss server on redhat linux

Tags: java, linux, jboss, redhat, jna

I am getting the unsatisfied link error when I try to run the web-app.

```
Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: libXXXX.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at deployment.ttt.war//com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at deployment.ttt.war//com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:191)
        ... 74 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: libXXXX.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at deployment.ttt.war//com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at deployment.ttt.war//com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:204)
        ... 74 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Native library (linux-x86-64/libXXXX.so) not found in resource path (/opt/jboss-eap-7.3/jboss-modules.jar)
        at deployment.ttt.war//com.sun.jna.Native.extractFromResourcePath(Native.java:1095)
        at deployment.ttt.war//com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:275)
        ... 74 more
```

1. I have created the function which loads the native library stored at "/home/libraryFiles", using JNA.
2. I have stored all of my libXXXX.so files at "/home/libraryFiles".
3. I have exporting my war file from eclipse in windows and deploying it on the jboss server on redhat linux.

This is my function :

```
public class function1(){

 public interface CLibrary extends Library {
     public int method1(String message);
 }

 public int execute (String param) throws Exception{

  NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("libXXXX", "home/libraryFiles");
  CLibrary pLib =(CLibrary)Native.loadLibrary("XXXX",CLibrary.class);
 return pLib.method1(param);

}
```

}

I am mapping url through rest controller to execute

```
new function1().execute("aaaaaaa");
```

I have also tried setting jna.library.path & java.library.path to "home/libraryFiles", but of no use. `(using system.setProperty())`
I also tried set `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH=home/libraryFiles` but still no good.

Seems like my web-app is not able to point out of the default resource path "/opt/jboss-eap-7.3/jboss-modules.jar"

Any help is welcoming.

PS :
I tried the same function/code on my windows PC, its working fine. I don't know why its not working on redhat linux.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: is `home` a relative directory to the JVM's current working directory?

Comment: The string you use in `addSearchPath()` is the map key searched for in `loadLibrary()`, so use either "XXXX" for both or "libXXXX" for both.

Comment: No "Home" is not the JVM's default working directory. I have set in using ld_library_path.

Comment: The point I'm making is in your code above you leave off the leading `/` before `home`, so it's relative in the Java code.  And the `addSearchPath()` isn't helping because you use a different string for the library name.

Comment: Oh sorry, I am using  "/home"  earlier also. I might have missed it here.  Seems like the reason is that my "home" directory has permission issues with the app. If I create a new directory with "rwx" permission it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I checked with addSearchPath() as you suggested. It is working fine. I didn't know that the method is storing it as key-value pair.

Comment: Great, I'll add that as an answer. I didn't know either until your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addSearchPath()` method is specific to a library, and the additional path(s) are stored in a map with the library name as the key.

The `loadLibrary()` method checks that map using the library name.

You have used differing strings as the key to store the path and retrieve it:

```java
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("libXXXX", "home/libraryFiles");
CLibrary pLib =(CLibrary)Native.loadLibrary("XXXX",CLibrary.class);
```

You should either change "libXXXX" to "XXXX" in the first line (probably the preferred style) or do the reverse in the second line to match.

As noted in the comments, you also must be careful with relative vs. absolute file paths and directory permissions.